# Cannot create Power BI Embedded resource in Azure portal

Tags: azure, powerbi

I followed tutorial in the link below to create Power BI Embedded resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-get-started

Surprisingly, it failed at step #3 - when i click the Power BI Embedded button, all I get is learn & learn links, no option to create the resource!

Anyone facing this problem?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but please check: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-migrate-from-powerbi-embedded/

Comment: I'm also having this exact same issue. I would be very keen to find out what the cause of the problem is.  About 2 months ago I followed the exact same method and it worked but now all that is shown is "learn more links"

Comment: Could this be down to Power Bi Embedded moving over the Power BI Service which means this isn't the correct way anymore. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-migrate-from-powerbi-embedded/

Answer (score 1):

As far as ventured to solve the problem, I got disappointed as Power BI announced in its [website](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embedding/) that Power BI service and Power BI embedded came together under a same umbrella beginning this month. So, you need at least Pro license to experience the embedded feature. Closing this as the answer, and thanks guys for all the efforts.